# Make chrome launch with command line switches without creating a shortcut

Tags: windows-8, command-line, google-chrome, shortcuts

I have a lot of command line switches appended to the end of my shortcut to Chrome, but every time I launch chrome without using the shortcut, it loses the switches. Also, when chrome is launched from an in-app call.

A good example is in the recent Chrome canary builds where it renders the title bar's and context menu's without GDI. A [quick fix](https://codereview.chromium.org/726893005/) was to use the switch: `--disable-directwrite-for-ui`. 
P.S: I use mactype

If you were to relaunch Chrome in Windows 8 mode, it loses the switch.

**Question:**

Is there any way to make Chrome work with command line switches without launching from a shortcut?

Comment: With `wmic process where "name='chrome.exe'" get CommandLine` command you can see all current switches `chrome` is running with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an environment variable like:

> `setx vChromeLaunchParamSet1 "C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -param1 -param2 -param3 -aram4"`

Then whenever you need to launch Chrome with your parameters, execute like this:

> `%vChromeLaunchParamSet1%`

or

> `start "" %vChromeLaunchParamSet1%`

or

> `start "My Extra Special Chrome Session" %vChromeLaunchParamSet1%`

Answer (score 2):

I am using **windows 10**. Hope its the same.

---

There is link how to do it with incognito. It is my main source of inspiration.
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/always-start-google-chrome-incognito-mode-default/

---

I found no uniform solution, but good results are reached by combining different solutions on different situations:

**links and HTML files:**

open `regedit.exe` and go to:

```
\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ChromeHTML\shell\open\command
```

The original value wil be something similar to:

```
"C:\Program Files (86x)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --"%1"
(there was no double hyphen (-) before "%1" on my PC)
```

Insert all parameters you want before "%1". Treat this as cmd command, where "%1" is new URL.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-directwrite-for-ui "%1"
```

**Icon pinned on toolbar**

This icon is shortcut. If you right-click it, on the pop-up window you can right-click the row titled "Google Chrome", which will lead you to properties. On the shortcut tab add your desired parameters in "Target" Editbox right after the path.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-directwrite-for-ui
```

**running from command line or other program**

Use `environment variable`, just as @wschloss proposed.

---

Those combined leave you with only running from start-menu as issue, which you can either avoid or call batch file instead "chrome.exe".

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution that will do the trick.

1. Rename your chrome.exe to chrome_real.exe
2. Create a batch file in the same directory and call it chrome.cmd. make that file launch chrome_real.exe with the arguments you want, for example: `chrome_real.exe --disable-directwrite-for-ui %*` (%* is used to append all arguments that your batch was called with).
3. Use a program to convert your batch file to exe, such as [this one](http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?pid=b2e). After this you'll have a "fake" chrome.exe file that calls the real chrome, but prepends your parameters to it. Since all programs are associated with calling chrome.exe and not chrome_real.exe, all of them will call your program which calls the original chrome, making it seamless.

Comment: Thanks for the quick hack, however this doesn't work for opening a file in Chrome from an external call, I just get the prompt `Windows can't find the file chrome_real.exe` when its in the same path as chrome.exe . Also for launching Chrome in Windows 8 mode.

Comment: Add a `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Application` (or whatever the path to chrome_real.exe is) as a first line in your batch file - that should solve it. As for Windows 8 mode, I'm not sure how exactly it works so I don't know whether this solution can help there.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt and change to the Chrome program folder, e.g.
CD \Users\Fred\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\

To find the folder on your PC you can right click on an existing Chrome shortcut, then "properties".

Then run chrome.exe with whatever switches you want, e.g. 
chrome.exe --app=https://superuser.com/